# when each is called on a hash, is there a way to reference the hash inside the block in a shorthand way

Tags: ruby

For example

I have a hash:

`@something = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}`

I could modify the hash as follows:

`@something.each { |(k,v)| @something[k] = v*2 }`

*is there a shorthand way of referring to the variable `@something` within the braces?*

This could also be solved by using `reduce` method which avoids the issue altogether but adds weight or converting to an array and using `map`.

Or is it just a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a shorthand way of referring to the variable @something within the braces?

Here's a sneaky one.  Use `instance_eval` along with a nested block so that you can simply reference `self`:

```
@something = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
@something.instance_eval {each{|k, v| self[k] = v*2}}
@something
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>6}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) instead of `each`:

```
@something = @something.transform_values{ |v| v * 2}
```

Now you don't need to reference `@something` at all since you are just creating a new hash.

Comment: Or simply ```@something.transform_values!...```?

Answer (score 2):

One might also use `#each_with_object` to build a new hash.

```rb
@something.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v * 2 }
# => {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although a better answer was already given, here are a couple other options:

Use `merge!` and just merge the original hash with itself;

```
@something = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
@something.merge!(@something) {|k, v| v*2}
@something
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>6}
```

Use `map`;

```
@something = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
@something = @something.map{|k, v| [k, v*2]}.to_h
@something
#=>  {:a=>2, :b=>4, :c=>6}
```